# Searching certain words from an input field

Tags: reactjs, search, full-text-search

I am building an order management system for my firm.
It has different tax for different items.
Like if the product contains led then it has 12%
and if the product doesn't contain led then it has 18%

And i have an input field where i can enter the product name.
So if the name contains led then it should calculate 12% or else 18%

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example for same you can modify your conditions as per your needs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [productPrice, setProductPrice] = useState(0);
  const [productName, setProductName] = useState("");
  const [finalProductPrice, setFinalProductPrice] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productName.toLowerCase().includes("led")) {
      setFinalProductPrice((productPrice * 12) / 100 + productPrice);
    } else {
      setFinalProductPrice((productPrice * 18) / 100 + productPrice);
    }
  }, [productName, productPrice]);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Product Price
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setProductPrice(parseInt(e.target.value))}
          type="number"
          value={productPrice}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Product Name
        <input
          type="text"
          value={productName}
          onChange={(e) => setProductName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      final price {finalProductPrice}
      {}
    </>
  );
}
```